# Python index error in a 2d array

Tags: python

So i am making a game involving a 2d array, and i ask the user to input a grid height and width, here is the code that makes the grid

```
Grid=[['O'for x in range(gridS[0])]for y in range(gridS[1])]
```

I later change gridS[0] and 1 to gridX and Y

then i try to add players into the grid, again I ask the user how many players (stored in variable opponents) are playing, then add that many players

```
            if opponents>0:
            Grid[gridX-1][gridY-2]='P'
            if opponents>1:
                Grid[0][(gridY-2)]='P'
                if opponents>3:
                    Grid[gridX-1][0]='P'
```

however, when testing, it comes up with this error:

```
>>> How many bots do you want to play against?
>>> 10
>>> Please enter a number between 0 and 3
>>> 2
2

    Grid[gridX-1][gridY-2]='P'
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: That is a *list* not an array.

Comment: my teacher said array - my bad

Comment: It is a pedantic point, and loosely, it could be referred to as an array, but it is better to be precise.

Comment: What do gridX and gridY hold before that line? Print them there and you will see your error

Comment: it holds a number between 6 and 12, which the user decides

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your nested comprehension constructs a nested array with the dimensions "flipped". Consider:

```
>>> dims = (4, 2)
>>> GRID = [['0' for x in range(dims[0])] for y in range(dims[1])]
>>> GRID
[['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

That would typically be called a *2X4* "matrix". And although that is a red flag, it is a notational issue. The fundamental problem is you are indexing into the *first* axis using `gridX, gridY = dims`. So:

```
>>> x, y = dims
>>> x
4
>>> len(GRID)
2
>>> GRID[x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

To make everything work out, use the following comprehension:

```
 Grid=[['O'for y in range(gridS[1])]for x in range(gridS[0])]
```

In other words, the inner-comprehension creates the second axis, the outer creates the first. But you were thinking about it in the opposite way.